# Динамический лист тасков

Tags: c#, tpl

Есть необходимость создать динамический список функций.

Есть `List<Task<Object>>` который хранит этот самый список, и функция добавления(Пока она имеет такой вид):

```
public void Add<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    listFunc.Add(new Func<Task<T>>(func));
}
```

Ругается на принимаемый func:

> 'T Func.Invoke()' Имеет неправильный возвращаемый тип

Как это правильно реализовать что бы могли и `void` функции приниматься, и например возвращающие `String`?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте базовый класс: `List<Task>`